# Print the last line beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

My example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen

base_url = 'https://book24.kz/catalog/klassicheskaya_proza/'

def BB_parse(base_url, headers):
        soup = bs(request.content, 'lxml')
        for pagination in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'pagination'}):
            for num in pagination.find_all('a'):
                rrr = num.getText().replace('Ctrl →','').replace("\n","")
            print(rrr)
```

Output:

```
2
3
37
38
```

So, how to output only the last line? (Like 38)

Comment: I guess you only have to take the 'print(rrr)' sentence out of the for loop.

Comment: use `[-1]` to get last element from list - ie. `.find_all(...)[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://book24.kz/catalog/klassicheskaya_proza/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("div", {'class': 'pagination'}):
    result = [tag.text for tag in item.findAll("a")]
    print(result[-2])
```